# Alternating between Fingers

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar

I am learning some classical guitar songs came to know about this rule :

If two notes or more notes are on the same string so they  are played with `M, I`,in that order.

So My question is if play in reverse order i.e `I, M` ? Will it create any difference because as per my experience  i noticed that reversing  the order create some sound difference  particularly  when there are more than 2 notes on the same string not sure why ?

Comment: we have this in bass guitar too. I found that if I lead with I(index), I end up producing SwingTime, whereas if I lead with M I get solid 4/4 time. Check that your timing is the same with each finger leading

Comment: @bigbadmouse - that's an interesting take on it. Never really thought about that aspect on bass. I use the same for straight and swing - must check timing!

Comment: Interesting to compare conventions. On bass I usually use index only (even for consecutive notes on the same string) for straight time, and switch to M then I for swing rhythm. On fingerstyle guitar, I lead with M then I. @SomPathak - I think you've received a good answer and I don't have anything substantial to add, but I wll say this: any time someone says to me, "this is the convention" and I'm curious, I just ask that person. So if a teacher told you this rule, maybe ask your teacher? They may not know, but maybe they have some nugget if wisdom for you!

Comment: @bigbadmouse - just restrung one of the fretless basses (5 string!) and had a chance to mess about. Seems I don't lead with anything in particular at any given time. I guess sometimes a finger that I could have used may be muting another string, so it's busy, or it's ready to play a different string. Just seems there's no particular pattern!

Comment: @bigbadmouse, why would swing necessitate different fingering?  One of the basic goals in classical guitar training is to ensure that there is NO gallop in the right hand regardless of finger order or speed.  Of course if the sheet music says to add swing or dotted eight sixteenth march pattern you need to do it as written.  I don't recall finger ordering being an issue in bass lessons either.  Can you illuminate?

Comment: i'm just alerting the OP to the fact that gallop can happen due to finger choices and that I had to depart from convention to get my timing right. In bass lessons and numerous books the RH fingering patterns indicate a start from I. I choose not to do that for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: @tim its just _my physiology_ and until a teacher pointed it out I had not noticed. I'm just telling OP about the effect so he is aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitting waiting, bored. Start tapping fingers on the table. Most people seem to start with pinky and work towards index. It seems to be a natural direction. So M comes before I. If that's not you, reader, then play I, then M !

Having said that, it's worth working on making exactly the same sound with each and every finger, and being able to play smoothly using any direction.Sometimes it's more convenient to be play something with the 'wrong' fingers. And two consecutive notes played on the same string might be A, M.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what rules you are finding or discovering.  Please take lessons for a while.

It is simply not true that (i, m) will sound different than (m, i).  They should not, that's what diligent practicing is for.  Also, notes on the same string do not need to be played (m,i,m,i, etc).  They can be played (a, m, i, a, m, i, etc) or even (i, m, a, m, repeat).  In fact that last pattern is very popular in classical guitar, appearing in the Segovia scale exercises. If you can master the (i, m, a, m) pattern on the right hand you can play with great speed.

Standard classical guitar approaches, Parkening, Segovia, Romero, etc emphasize working ALL combinations of fingering on all exercises for the sole purpose of ensuring that no particular finger combination will "sound different".  The guitarists is working towards control of their extremities and the ability to create an accent with any finger on any fraction of a beat.  Locking in to one pattern for the sake of simplicity will lead to a lack of technique.

If you look at arrangements of guitar music by the greats you will find left and right hand fingerings that seem counter intuitive at first but the logic becomes clear once the piece is mastered.  Typically one works towards economy of movement and the need for clear transitions between chords to avoid squeaks and scrapes, as well as avoiding buzzing of the strings against the picking hand just before attack.  Some "rules of thumb" that and frequently broken are (1) never use the same finger twice in a sequence, (2) Always use the ring finger on the high e string when plucking chords, (3) always use a rest stroke on the last note of a line, etc.  None of these are true "rules" but some people tend to like them.  For beginners there is enough to learn and too many options can cause confusion.  Carcassi, for example, recommends using the thumb only on the bass strings and the index, middle and ring fingers on the top strings in succession, (i, m, r) = (g, b, e).  This is merely a beginner approach and he violates it in later books.  Again, gotta start somewhere.

Parkening has an exercise in his beginner book where the student plays a chromatic line (1, 2, 3, 4) on frets (1, 2, 3, and 4).  The FAMOUS 1-2-3-4 exercise.  He has the student pluck each note 4 times using finger combinations (i, m), (i, a), (m, a), both free and rest stroke, all they way up the neck and across all strings.

In Segovia's famous scale exercises he has the student play each scale 7 different ways all the way up and back; (i, m), (m, i), (a, i), (i, a), (m, a), (a, m), and (i, m, a, m), all rest stroke.  Others have added to this (p, i), (i, p), (p, m), (m, p), (p, a), (a, p) in free stroke.  Still others add free stroke to all these combos when possible.  And finally Elliot Fisk (a Segovia student) has added the pinky of the picking hand to all combinations.